# How to generate cucumber report if I use knapsack

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber, knapsack-problem

I run tests in parallel in my jenkins pipeline job using knapsack. I need json report after job for Cucumber reports plugin.
Now I run cucumber like:

`bundle exec rake knapsack:cucumber`

But for plugin I need run cucumber with parameters `-f json -o cucumber.json`:

`bundle exec rake knapsack:cucumber -- -f json -o cucumber.json`

But after this job report didin't genereted.

When I try run `cucumber -f json -o cucumber.json` report genereted.

How can I generate report with knapsack?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example from documentation:

```
bundle exec rake "knapsack_pro:cucumber[--name feature]"
```

So, try to use `""` like:

```
bundle exec rake "knapsack:cucumber[--format json --out cucumber.json]"
```

https://github.com/KnapsackPro/knapsack_pro-ruby#passing-arguments-to-cucumber

Hope it will help you!

Comment: If I run 
`bundle exec rake "knapsack:cucumber -f json -o cucumber.json"`
I get error:
`Don't know how to build task 'knapsack:cucumber -- -f json -o cucumber.json'`

Comment: @Giwery Did you use --f or -f ?

Comment: `bundle exec rake "knapsack:cucumber[--format json --out cucumber.json]"`
Solve the problem. Thanks.